# Auto connect to VPN when WiFi connects, on a Windows 10 OS?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, vpn

Is it possible to have a specific VPN Connection auto connect when a WiFi network is connected on a Windows 10 OS?

Right now my wifi network(s) auto connect when the WiFi network is detected (e.g. work wifi, home wifi). I would also like the VPN to auto connect *ASAP* so (hopefully) no (important) network traffic is passed over the wifi network once the connection handshake/dance has completed.

Is this possible?

Comment: What VPN client are you using? If Windows VPN client, then no, this is not possible. It would be great if it was. There are multiple ways to script `rasdial` which can connect it for you. I wrote a service application a number of years ago to force a VPN active. Most other third party clients have the capability.

Comment: yeah @Appleoddity - it's the stock standard VPN client built into Windows 10.